# while loop in bash that uses pgrep to check if service exists

Tags: bash, service, command

Can someone explain to me why this doesn't work?

```
  /usr/bin/mysqld_safe
  STATUS=$(/usr/bin/pgrep mysql | wc -l)
  while $STATUS -eq 0; do
    echo "$STATUS"
    sleep 1
  done
```

It defies any logic. Yes I'm not versed in bash :)

p.s. I'm trying to wait till service is up, but after running this even echo "$STATUS" is not printed! so loop is not running

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This runs `mysqld_safe`:

```
  /usr/bin/mysqld_safe
```

This runs `pgrep` and stores the result in STATUS:

```
  STATUS=$(/usr/bin/pgrep mysql | wc -l)
```

STATUS is never updated again.  This loops using a constant fixed value of STATUS:

```
  while $STATUS -eq 0; do
    echo "$STATUS"
    sleep 1
  done
```

Note that the test in the while loop is malformed.  It should read:

```
  while [ "$STATUS" -eq 0 ]; do
```

To get live updates, `pgrep` should be run within the loop.  Further, because `pgrep` sets an exit code, the test command, `[...]`, is superfluous:

To keep the loop running while there are no instances of mysql:

```
while ! /usr/bin/pgrep mysql >/dev/null; do
```

`pgrep` returns success (exit code=0) when it finds a matching process.  Since you seem to want the loop to repeat when there is no matching process, we invert the exit code using `!`.

Or, putting it all back together:

```
/usr/bin/mysqld_safe
while ! /usr/bin/pgrep mysql >/dev/null; do
    echo "No such process"
    sleep 1
done
```

Assuming that `mysqld_safe` successfully starts, the `while` loop will never run.  You should only see output from the while loop is `mysqld_safe` fails to start.

If you instead want a continuous status update:

```
/usr/bin/mysqld_safe
while true; do
    /usr/bin/pgrep mysql >/dev/null
    echo "Current status: $?"
    sleep 1
done
```

Comment: @salivan Please clarify:  Which part of the code did you try?  What did you want it to do? And, what actually happened when you tried it?

Comment: I don't receive No such process notice.

Comment: @salivan That would seem to indicate that mysql had started, as it should have in the first line.  Run `pgrep mysql` at the command line to verify.

Comment: I've another echo after Done and its never triggered. this is super fishy.

Comment: @salivan Also, try the code I just added (maybe requiring a screen refresh) which provides continuous status update whether it mysql is running or not.

Comment: I'm building a docker container, maybe its worth saying.

Comment: @salivan I haven't used docker.  So, I may be missing some context.

Comment: So basically, it hangs on /usr/bin/mysqld_safe this line makes my bash script hang indefinitely

Comment: @salivan OK.  As I understand `mysqld_safe` [from here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/637185/how-to-start-mysqld-through-mysqld-safe), it should start `mysqld` in the background and then control should return to the terminal.  If it hangs on `mysqld_safe`, that would seem to mean that the problem is in the `mysqld_safe` setup and not in the shell script.

Comment: I checked mysqld_safe has infinite loop. so I changed my code to use service instead.

Answer (score 2):

perhaps a solution could be something like this

```
STATUS=0
while [ $STATUS -eq 0 ]; do
    echo $STATUS
    sleep 1
    STATUS=$(/usr/bin/pgrep mysql | wc -l)
done
```

one needs to update the `STATUS` variable within the loop to reflect the current status.

Comment: damn! I need to reed more about bash, I thought I was making an alias for the command. One more question where do I read about -eq -ne etc?

Comment: an overview can be found e.g. at http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html